# Ninject inject model asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, ninject, inject

I am using Ninject and I want to inject a property of my model.I have the following model

```
public class TCFormModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IPNConBut pConBut { get; set; }
}
```

I want to inject `IPNConBut` with my `ConBut` class which implements `IPNConBut`.

```
public class ConBut : IPNConBut { ... }
```

How can I do this?

LATER EDIT - MORE INFO:

My model is used in a binder and it fails when it tries to create an instance of TCFormModel. It makes sense but how can avoid this? I tried with two constructors, one parameterless and one with the binding parameter. I also tried [Inject] on property and even on constructor and I had the same results. The constructor is never used.

```
public class TCFormModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionKey = "TCFM_Model";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        TCFormModel model = null;
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
            model = (TCFormModel)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
        }

        if (model == null)
        {
            model = new TCFormModel();
            if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = model;
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Factory interface:

```
public interface IPNConButFactory
{
    IPNConBut Create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either us constructor injection:

```
public class TCFormModel
{
    public TCFormModle(IPNConBut pConBut) {
        this.pConBut = pConBut;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IPNConBut pConBut { get; set; }
}
```

(which is usually recommend)
or property injection:

```
public class TCFormModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IPNConBut pConBut { get; set; }
}
```

Also see:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns

And generally the wiki: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki

Update:

I recommend using the https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory extension.

Bind your factory interface as follows:

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<IPNConButFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Then, in `TCFormModelBinder` inject the `IPNConButFactory` and use it to create an instance. The Model should only need one constructor in case of constructor injection, or no (=default ctor) in case of property injection.

I'm not familiar with asp.net MVC so i'm not certain whether you can actuall inject something into `TCFormModelBinder` but i would guess so. At any rate, if you can't, you need to access the `IKernel` somehow and retrieve the factory from there.

Comment: Yes but the problem is if I create a new model like `new TCFormModel()` it will need a parameter and I cannot send anything. What should I do in this case? This doesn't solve my problem. It will say that doesn't know what IPNConBut parameter is.